# VBA - Range to jpg picture

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to get a jpg file from a specific range in excel

I'm currently getting the

> 1004 Runtime error on Range method from _Worksheet object.

This is what my code looks like:

```
Sub Export()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Chrt As Chart

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set Rng = Range("B2:H11")

ws.Range(Rng).CopyPicture
Set Chrt = Charts.Add

With Chrt
    .Paste
    .Export FileName = "Case.jpg", Filtername:="JPG"
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You'll need to specify the path `.Export FileName = "C:\Case.jpg", Filtername:="JPG"`

Comment: Won't it save to the path where the excel file is located in case I don't specify it?

Comment: You should also change `Set Rng = Range("B2:H11")` to `Set Rng = ws.Range("B2:H11")` and then `ws.Range(Rng).CopyPicture` to `rng.CopyPicture`.

Comment: Missing `:` before `=` in `.Export FileName = ` ?

Comment: Pro tip: PNG is more suited to screenshots than JPG.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60537934/saving-excel-range-as-a-picture/76478367#76478367), I made a portable function for general use.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The main error has @J_Lard mentioned already in his comment.

But I would use `ChartObject` rather than a `Chart` sheet. Whith this you can determine the size of the output instead of getting the whole chart area in the picture.

And while using `F8` step the paste and export will work, while real time run, the `ChartObject` needs to be activated.

```
Sub Export()

 Dim oWs As Worksheet
 Dim oRng As Range
 Dim oChrtO As ChartObject
 Dim lWidth As Long, lHeight As Long

 Set oWs = ActiveSheet
 Set oRng = oWs.Range("B2:H11")

 oRng.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
 lWidth = oRng.Width
 lHeight = oRng.Height

 Set oChrtO = oWs.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=lWidth, Height:=lHeight)

 oChrtO.Activate
 With oChrtO.Chart
  .Paste
  .Export Filename:="Case.jpg", Filtername:="JPG"
 End With

 oChrtO.Delete

End Sub
```

If path is not specified, the `Case.jpg` will be saved in default 
save location. This is probably your user documents directory `C:\Users\YourName\Documents\`

Comment: Thanks, that got it working. What format would you recommend me to export it so I can get the best image quality since it's for a report?

Comment: Hm, it depends ;-). My favorite is definitely PNG. Using `xlPicture` instead of `xlBitmap` I have provided already. But also this depends. Try different formats, compare the results and choose what is the best in your opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to export in the same path as the workbook :

```
Sub Export()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Chrt As Chart
Dim ExportPath As String

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set Rng = ws.Range("B2:H11")
ExportPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Case.jpg"

Set Chrt = ThisWorkbook.Charts.Add
Rng.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap   

With Chrt
    .Paste
    .Export FileName:=ExportPath, Filtername:="JPG"
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Now it's generating an empty sheet in excel (Where I'm guessing the chart should show up) and a file named "False" in the directory.

This is what the excel sheet looks like:
http://i.imgur.com/NsqNrdN.jpg

Might this be caused because of the combined cells?

Comment: Great, now we're getting the picture with both the name and extension expected but it still shows blank both in excel and the .jpg :/

Answer (score 0):

I had to add

> Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:15"))

Answer (score 0):

My Excel VBA solution

1. range.Select
2. range.CopyPicture
3. Paste it
4. Cut it for storing to system clipboard ( key-point )
5. create windows powershell command in one-line
6. execute powershell by Shell

```vb
     Sub 巨集1()
        PicDir = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
        PicFile = Format(Now(), "hh-mm") & ".png"
        Sheets("工作表1").Select
        Range("Q1:U10").CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture '複製範圍成圖檔
        ActiveSheet.Paste '要利用這動作-1，才會真的存到 Clipboard
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array(Selection.ShapeRange.Name)).Select '選剛貼上的 Shape
        Selection.Cut '要利用這動作-2，才會真的存到 Clipboard
        sPSCmd = "powershell $img = get-clipboard -format image ; $img.Save('" & PicDir & PicFile & "')" '把 Clipboard 內容存成圖檔的 PowerShell
        RetVal = Shell(sPSCmd, 0) '無聲無息的執行
    End Sub
```

Comment: Can you use English instead of Chinese characters ?
It improves he readibility for everybody.