# Saving range as picture with Excel 2016

Tags: vba, excel

The purpose of this code is to save a range of cells as a picture on the desktop.

The file is created but does not contain any of the cell data, it is a blank image with the relative size of the range.

The problem appears in Office 2016. Works in 2013.

```
Sub SendSnapshot2()

    Dim strRng As Range
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim Cht As Chart

    Set strRng = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Snapshot").Range("A2:Q31")
    strPath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop")
    strFile = "HeartBeat Snapshot - " & Format(Now(), "yyyy.mm.dd.Hh.Nn") & ".png"

    strRng.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap
    'strRng.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    'strRng.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set Cht = Charts.Add
    With Cht
        .Paste
        '.Export Filename:=strFile, Filtername:="JPG"
        .Export Filename:="C:\downloads\SavedRange.jpg", Filtername:="JPG"
        '.Delete
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: So the problem is with saving the file, and not with the email right? i.e. After `cht.Chart.Export strPath & "\" & strFile`, is the file created on your computer also a blank image? If that's the case, maybe consider reducing the scope of your question to exclude the email half. As a debugging step, I would check `cht` after `cht.Chart.Paste` to see if it's blank in Excel before you export it.

Comment: Correct. The image is saved, however the image is blank. My guess is that there is a problem with the conversion of the cell content to an image. Not sure how to go about this TBH...

Comment: I suggest editing your question then, leave off everything about the email and be clear that the image is saving as a blank.

Comment: I think it is rather clear already from the problem description that I have given. I rather keep the whole code in case any solution requires changes to the email segment later. I trust the problem is explained clearly enough, lets see what solutions come back.

Comment: Have you tried passing different argument to `.CopyPicture` like `.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap` or `.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture`

Comment: Not sure of the answer - Ron de Bruin has a fair amount about email workbooks/ranges on his website.  Was just commenting to say you don't need `Activeworkbook.Application.Screenupdating....`, just `Application.Screenupdating....` will do it (`ActiveWorkbook.Application` & `Application` will both point to Excel).

Comment: Please provide a MINIMAL example of your code. Reproducing only the error, not everything that does work. That will greatly help you narrowing down your question, and help us answer it.

Comment: Thanks. I did some more googling and used other solutions from SE which didnt work either. The problem seems to be related to the `strRng.CopyPicture' bit since `cht` is also empty. Perhaps something in O2016 changed?

Comment: code updated. For reference, neither of those solutions mentioned here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143877/using-vba-code-how-to-export-excel-worksheets-as-image-in-excel-2003) seem to work either. must be a change from Office 2003 to 2016

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42091390/vba-range-to-jpg-picture/42092375#42092375

Comment: @AxelRichter Thank you, that solved it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Axel Richter who pointed me over to this thread: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42091390/vba-range-to-jpg-picture/42092375#42092375)

The successful code looks like this:

```
' convert snapshot to picture
strRng.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
lWidth = strRng.Width
lHeight = strRng.Height

Set Cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=lWidth, Height:=lHeight)
Cht.Activate
With Cht.Chart
  .Paste
  .Export Filename:=strPath & "\" & strFile, Filtername:="JPG"
End With

Cht.Delete
```