# Send message from Excel to Telegram with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, telegram, telegram-bot

I am using below code to send message from my Excel file to Telegram. It works fine but the only problem is, I can send message only from a single cell, for example `("G9")`. If I select a range like `("A1:B3")`, then my code does not work.

Here's the code:

```
Sub Send_Message()
Dim objRequest As Object
Dim strChatID As String
Dim strMessage As String
Dim strPostData As String

strChatID = Sheets("Control").Range("C3").Value
strMessage = Range("G9").Value
strPostData = "chat_id=" & strChatID & "&text=" & strMessage
Set objRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

With objRequest
    .Open "POST", "https://api.telegram.org/bot:xxxxxxxxx/sendMessage?", False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    .Send (strPostData)
End With

End Sub
```

Any suggestion what modification should I do to send an entire range? Thanks

Comment: You need to concatenate the cell values first (ex.: `strMessage = Range("G9").Value & Range("G10").Value & Range("G11").Value` )

Comment: This works but my range is a table and I want the same formatting. Is there a way I can send the data as picture instead of text?

Comment: Does Telegram even accept any kind of table? If yes, you'll probably have to populate it cell by cell. (or maybe convert the table into an image?)

Comment: Converting the table into an image would help but I'm sorry, I don't know how to do that.

Comment: This question might help, as it shows now to copy a range as an image
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48399832/saving-range-as-picture-with-excel-2016

Answer (score 1):

You need to change this line:

```
strMessage = Range("G9").Value
```

To:

```
strMessage = Application.TextJoin(Chr(10), True, Range("A1", "B3"))
```

This will give you a cleaner string from the range of cells.