# Saving a graph from excel as a separate image file using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, image, charts, export

I want to produce a gif which shows a chart of mine updating overtime. I need to take a graph, save it as an image, refresh the data the chart is using (to move to the next time period) and save the graph again as seperate file.

The aim is to produce a folder of chart images, at different time steps, which I can then collate into a gif, showing the data changing over time.

I've managed to get the chart to refresh with new data, but I can't for the life of me work out how to export a chart as a separate image file.

Cheers.

Comment: I think that your question already exists: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42091390/vba-range-to-jpg-picture     I hope that this will do the trick

Comment: That did indeed do the trick! Must have missed it in my search, thank you kindly.

Comment: @Edward Hampson you are very welcome!