# Saving excel range as a picture

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet that has several charts and images which is used as a dashboard. I need to save the content in the area as an image. I found this code to save the area as an image:

```
Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Graphical Dashboard")
Set strRng = sht.Range("I1:AC124") ' range to be copied

strRng.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
lWidth = strRng.Width
lHeight = strRng.Height

Set Cht = sht.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=lWidth, Height:=lHeight)
Cht.Activate
Set oCht = Charts.Add

With oCht
    .Paste
    .Export Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\SavedRange.jpg", Filtername:="JPG"
End With

Cht.Delete
```

But, the problem is, although it saves an image which matches the area of the selected range, the image is **blank**. Additionally, it adds another sheet named 'Chart' and pastes the blank image to sheet.

Comment: with `Set oCht = Charts.Add` you are adding a new blank chart

Comment: But, when it is removed, what should be given for the 'With oCht' when the Charts.Add is removed?

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, excel file already contains the charts in specified range, So there is no need to add chart object `Set Cht = sht.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=lWidth, Height:=lHeight)`.

I have Tested the following code and it is working.

```
Private Sub Test()
Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set strRng = sht.Range("A1:B2") ' range to be copied
Dim oCht As Chart
strRng.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
lWidth = strRng.Width
lHeight = strRng.Height
Set oCht = Charts.Add
With oCht
    .Paste
    .Export Filename:="D:\SavedRange.jpg", Filtername:="JPG"
End With
End Sub
```

And if chart is not there in excel and you want to draw in VBA then you will have to set source data in Chart.
`.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B2")`

Answer (score 0):

Well doing whole thing VBA didn't work for me. Therefore, I have used below approach.

1. Select and copy the range from macro.

   ```
   ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Graphical Dashboard").Activate
   Range("H80:AB121").Select
   Selection.Copy
   ```
2. Save the content from clipboard as an image.

   ```
   # invoke the macro
   xlapp.Application.Run("SelectRangeMacro")

   # save the area as a image
   im = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
   im.save('somefile.png','PNG')
   ```

Comment: As far as i know ‘ImageGrab.grabclipboard()’ works in python

Answer (score 0):

First I select the range I need to copy and use the method .CopyPicture, then I clear all current pictures out of the workbook if the type is msoPicture, then I paste the image into the worksheet in order to add it to the chart, I then add the copied picture to the chart, export it, and remove the chart when I'm finished.

```
Dim oCht, oChtArea, pic
Range("B2:AI5").CopyPicture
'On Error Resume Next

For Each pic In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MonthlyRevenue").Shapes 'Deleting pics before copying next one in
    If pic.Type = msoPicture Then
        Debug.Print pic.Name
        pic.Delete
    End If
Next

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MonthlyRevenue").Pictures.Paste
    .Left = Range("C15").Left
    .Top = Range("C15").Top
    .Name = "monthRevPic"
End With

For Each pic In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MonthlyRevenue").Shapes
    If pic.Type = msoPicture Then
        Debug.Print pic.Name
        pic.Copy
        'SavePicture pic, "C:\temp\tempchart.jpg"
        Set oCht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, pic.Width, pic.Height)
        Set oChtArea = oCht.Chart
        With oChtArea
            .Paste
            .Export ("C:\temp\tempchart.jpg")
        End With
        oCht.Delete
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I made this portable function that works in any scenario and has some cool features liks Zoom levels and automatic save as file dialog:

```
'Saves a range as image file on disc
' Parameters:
'   * rng = the range to save as image
'   * filename = File path and name of image. If ommited, a save as dialog is used. Accepted formats: .JPG, .BMP and .GIF. OPTIONAL.
'   * Zoom = Zoom to apply to the image before saving. Example: Zoom of 200 will make image twice the actual size.
' Returns: True = success
'
Public Function Save_Range_snapshot_as_image(rng As Range, Optional filename As String = "", Optional Zoom As Double = 100) As Boolean
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim ChO As ChartObject
  Dim OldZoom As Single
    
    'Setup
    On Error GoTo ErrorCatch
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Set ws = rng.Worksheet
    ws.Activate
    OldZoom = ActiveWindow.Zoom
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = Zoom
    
    'Create temporary chart
    rng.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
    Set ChO = ws.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=rng.Left, Top:=rng.Top, Width:=WorksheetFunction.Min(rng.Width + 100, 169056), Height:=rng.Height + 100)
    ChO.Activate
    With ChO.Chart
        .parent.Border.LineStyle = 0
        .Paste
        .ChartArea.Width = .Shapes(1).Width - 6
        .ChartArea.Height = .Shapes(1).Height - 6
        .Shapes(1).ScaleWidth 1, msoTrue
    End With
    
    'Save chart image to file
    If filename = "" Then
    filename = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(fileFilter:="Portable Networks Graphic (*.png),*.png, JPEG (*.jpg),*.jpg, Bitmap (*.bmp), *.bmp, GIF (*.gif), *.gif,")
        If CStr(filename) = CStr(False) Then GoTo cancel
    End If
    If ChO.Chart.Export(filename) Then Save_Range_snapshot_as_image = True

cancel:
    'Clean up
    On Error Resume Next
    ChO.Delete
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = OldZoom
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Function
ErrorCatch:
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then Resume Else Stop  'Unhandled Error occured
End Function
```