# How to copy a specific range in excel and save it as an image using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy a range (suppose A1 to D5) and save this as an image using vba.

I have tried using the provided code and it worked fine but the image is blank only white.

```
Sub SaveRangeAsImage()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim chartObj As ChartObject

    Set ws = Workbooks("IMPORTANT.xlsx").Worksheets("Imp")
    Set rng = ws.Range("A10:B14")

    Set chartObj = ws.ChartObjects.add(Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=rng.Width, Height:=rng.Height)

    rng.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    chartObj.Chart.Paste

    chartObj.Chart.Export "D:\Imp\Test15.png", "PNG"
    chartObj.DELETE
End Sub
```

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60537934/16578424 or here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48401601/16578424

Comment: @Nick Abbot No need of any `SourceData` to paste and export picture.

Comment: You may want to review this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69078073/3688861

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next adapted code. It looks that the chart must be activated before pasting the picture range:

```
Sub SaveRangeAsImage()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range
    Dim chartObj As ChartObject

    Set ws = Workbooks("IMPORTANT.xlsx").Worksheets("Imp")
    Set rng = ws.Range("A10:B14")

    Set chartObj = ws.ChartObjects.Add(left:=0, top:=0, width:=rng.width, height:=rng.height)

    rng.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    ws.Parent.Activate: ws.Activate: chartObj.Activate: ActiveChart.Paste '!!!

    chartObj.Chart.Export "D:\Imp\Test15.png", "PNG"
    chartObj.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: @Nick Abbot What does "dosn't work" mean? Did you test it? It does not need **any SourceData**!

Comment: @Nick Abbot I also tested it and the image looks exactly as the respective range appearance. This is not first time I use such an approach to save ranges as picture...